# How can I stream audio from my desktop to a WiFi speaker?

Tags: wireless, sound, speakers

I have a [Roberts Wifi speaker](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Roberts-R-Line-S1-Wireless-Speaker/dp/B008VRWLBK/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1547292903&sr=8-2&keywords=roberts%20speaker) that is capable of playing DLNA served content. How can I make this speaker available in my Ubuntu "Sound" settings so that I can send my desktop's audio output to it?

EDIT: At one point I did download a daemon that made this possible - but I've lost sight of it.

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted it out, now. It is `pulseaudio-dlna` and it works well for me. Just `sudo apt install pulseaudio-dlna`.

I installed it as a Startup Application:

[image]

It now shows any available DLNA speaker:
[image]