# Can't stream audio to wifi speaker

Tags: networking, wireless, sound, pulseaudio, centrino

I have read the solution in [How can I stream audio from my desktop to a WiFi speaker?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109118/how-can-i-stream-audio-from-my-desktop-to-a-wifi-speaker) and have followed that solution.

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 I have a Bose Soundtouch 20 connected to the network. My cell phone serves as a hotspot and my speaker, printer and computer are all connected to the network.

I followed the instructions in the above linked post and after rebooting the speaker appears in the list of available output devices as SoundTouch 20-Bose SoundTouch 331D2C (DLNA). When I ping the speakers ip address I get a response and I can browse to the speaker's onboard configuration page, which only allows for selecting a network and inputting a password.So I know the speaker is connected to my network.

When I try to test the speaker, the output automatically switches back to my HDMI output off of my monitor, which was working before the cable went bad.

The output of `uname -a` is

```
Linux "XXXXXXXXX" 5.3.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 09:22:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
```

Is there an additional configuration that would stream all audio from the computer to the WiFi speaker, other than that posted in the above answered question?

This is the message that keeps popping up when I test the speaker.

> Device “Soundtouch 20 – Bose Soundtouch 331D2C (DLNA) 
>   Unknown reason. Your stream switched back to GK104 HDMI Audio Controller.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, it turns out that Bose only allows streaming to its speakers with one of its apps for android, iPhone. They also have an app for streaming from PCs and Mac desktops. The solution is to connect via Bluetooth. The issue is there is sometimes a delay in the audio up to several seconds.

Comment: What a pity, would love to use something different than Spotify to use Soundtouch.