# BoseSound 20 external wifi speaker does not show on output device list

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have been attempting to connect to an external Bosesound 20 speaker. I have been using the speaker with an audio cable, but now have two computers to connect to it. I seem to only be able to find directions for connecting via Bluetooth. This speaker has the ability to connect to it via WiFi. I have it connected to my home network. I followed the instructions here [How can I stream audio from my desktop to a WiFi speaker?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109118/how-can-i-stream-audio-from-my-desktop-to-a-wifi-speaker). It took a bit of doing, but was able to load and use Pulseaudio preference gui. I also enable everything on Network Server tab.[image: PulseAudio preferences Network Access]

I rebooted the system just to make sure everything would load as expected, but the speaker does not load to the audio output list.

[image: Audio output list does not show external speaker.]

I would appreciated any guidance to getting this speaker connected via wifi ratter than Bluetooth. I can find many instructions for connecting via Bluetooth, but not via wifi.